# Bathtub install

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, installation

[image]Our contractor installed a new Kohler Villager tub, dimensions 60"L x 30-1/4"W x 14"H during a complete bathroom renovation, including floor.

The end result is a tub height of 11.5”H from finished floor.

GC thinks it’s fine.  I think it looks submerged.

This is a remodel.  And happened because the tub was installed first.  The cabinetry 2nd.  The tile floor 3rd.  Then when they were integrating with the adjacent bedroom new floor realized there was an elevation discrepancy.  To resolve, they tore up the bathroom tile floor, changed its elevation to meet the bedroom floor thus reducing the height of the exposed bathtub side.

Is this an acceptable implementation in the construction business?

Please see the attached images and spec from KOHLER to help illustrate.

[image]

Comment: pics would help us .  How is the tub 2.5 inches lower than the floor.  Was it installed directly on the floor joists, like done in 1945?

Comment: As long as it is installed in a safe/sturdy way, having a shorter distance from top of wall of tub to floor is an advantage in getting in and out for a lot of people.

Comment: "What would you do?" is off-topic.  Please focus instead on what your concerns are.  For example, are you asking if it is up to code?  Concerned that it is a trip hazard?  Likely to cause moisture damage to the joists?  Not supported properly?  Do you just not like it and want reasons that the general contractor might accept to change it?

Comment: 2 things: does your contract specify the install? And does the install conform to manufacturer’s instructions?

Comment: The manufacturer's picture shows the tub resting on the subfloor, and the floor built up around the tub, which sounds like what your contractor did. Note the tub in that picture is set 0.5" into the floor, but Kohler of course does not know the thickness of whatever floor you're putting down on top of the subfloor. 2.5" may be a bit on the high side, but it's the same principle.

Comment: Thank you and understood.  But what’s the threshold?  Using similar logic, leaving an exposed tub side of say 8 inches is acceptable from a construction perspective?

Comment: As part of good customer care, the GC should have discussed this. If the remodel is different from the old by a "material" difference (so 0.5 would not count, but 3in perhaps would), you may have cause to demand a fix. However, there is nothing -I think- that violates code since there is no tub seat and no dropped ceiling.

Comment: Thank you.  Appreciate your response.